# Strange CSS overwrite class issue

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

i i have one little issue on [my site](http://touchdowner.cz/digitalni-produkty/produkt/808-touchdown-v1/) that dont can fix myself. I use plugin [WooCommerce Quick View](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-quick-view/) and all is working fine. But want to change background color of that button. I found this class:

```
.woocommerce a.button,.woocommerce-page a.button,.woocommerce 
button.button,.woocommerce-page button.button,.woocommerce 
input.button,.woocommerce-page input.button,.woocommerce #respond 
input#submit,.woocommerce-page #respond input#submit,.woocommerce #content 
input.button,.woocommerce-page #content input.button {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        background: #fff !important;
        box-shadow: none
    }
```

When insert this color into custom CSS, and update to my values, nothing is changed. i don can fine right class or?

Comment: Use browser inspector to track the element style - you will see what selector is overwriting it.

Comment: I used but cant find it.

Comment: The background of Quick view button **is** white, you have no issues as far as I can see. I am watching it on [this page](http://touchdowner.cz/digitalni-produkty/kategorie-produktu/sound-kits/drum-kits/).

Comment: I want to make it blue background.. For that im asking why i cant overwrite that !important rule.

Comment: For example if i insert class from my topic, and change background from #fff to some other color, nothing is changed, Understand me what is issue?

Comment: To override an !important thing you need to have a bigger specificity score when targeting the element.
So you may add `#layout` before your current selectors.

eg: `.woocommerce #layout a.button`

That's why !important is in most case a bad practice.

Comment: That makes sense.. Can you post that as answer so i can accept your answer as accepted. This makes change in my situation:

`.woocommerce #layout a.button.quick-view-button`

Comment: Your styles are before the plugin styles inside the Head. If you put them after, than you can use same specificity.

Answer (score 0):

Because none of people dont post asnwer  i want to post working sollution for m y problem.

```
.woocommerce #layout a.button.quick-view-button
{
 CSS stylings goes here
 }
```